# why org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping is not working?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

I am beginner in Spring Mvc.
i have use   BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping  .
After Completed all mapping when i call the page from url ,404 error is occurs.
How i will solve this.

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" 
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
<!-- Default hander mapping -->
<!-- handler -->

<bean  id="HandlerMapping" class=" org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
<!-- controller -->

<bean name="/hello.html" class="main.Hellocontroller"></bean>







<!-- View Reserver -->
<bean id="viewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF"/>
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>Spring</display-name>

  <!-- Default Configuration -->
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>


  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Hellocontroller.java

package main;

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class Hellocontroller extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ModelAndView mdvAndView=new ModelAndView("Hellopage");
        mdvAndView.addObject("messege","Welcome .View this page");

        return mdvAndView;
    }

}
```

Hellopage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hiiii</h1>
<h1>


${messege} 

</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any exceptions in your logfile when starting your application?

Comment: @jens **no exception**

Comment: url pattern for your dispatcher servlet is `*.do` and for controller is `hello.html`. update url pattern of dispatcher servlet to `*.html`

Comment: @ Md Zahid Raza if do this change then  1 exception show .  "HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception"javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception.org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]

Comment: It is strange. The exception isn't related to changing the url pattern of dispatcher servlet.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use @Controller annotation for controller class and no need to extend abstractcontroller class. make the url of dispatcher servlet `/`.

Comment: i used  and @Controller
public class Hellocontroller {
  
 @RequestMapping("/welcome")
 
 public ModelAndView helloworld(){
  
  ModelAndView mdvAndView=new ModelAndView("Hellopage");
  mdvAndView.addObject("messege","Welcome page");
 
return mdvAndView;
  
  
 }but can't call this page

Comment: @Md Zahid Raza where i am doing wrong .suggest me

Comment: Did you change dispatcher pattern url to `/`.   Are you getting any errors.  Post the code of Jsp pages and controller after you have made changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to make things clear by modifying your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" 
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.springmvc" /> <!-- base package where spring will scan for Component like Controller,Service,Repository etc-->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- View Reserver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

your jsp pages should be inside WEB-INF Directory. Note that prefix should be "/WEB-INF/" not "/WEB-INF"

your web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>Spring</display-name>

  <!-- Default Configuration -->
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Your Controller

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/home"})
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/welcome"})
    public String index(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message","Welcome to Web Application!");
        return "Hellopage";
    }

}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home Page </h1>
        <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/welcome">Click Here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hellopage.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello Page </h1>
        ${requestScope.message}
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure, your jsp pages are inside WEB-INF directory.

Comment: .Will you take some time from your busy schedule.I will show you all in TeamViewer.If any chance.same error show.HTTP Status 404 -

Comment: I have created a demo project for you. you can download from [here](https://github.com/mzraza2/SpringMVCDemo) and study complete code

Comment: I have also edited spring configuration file. You may can modify and see if  your project is working. If not, download the demo project and see complete details